# Script to add rows, shift data and add characters for Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running a project in Google Docs and I need help with a script. I need one that will perform the following tasks in a two column spreadsheet.

1. Insert a new blank row between every existing row of data.
2. Shift the data in the second column down one place so that they occupy the newly inserted blank row
3. Add curly brackets {} to the text in the data of the second column *ie* **anytext --> {anytext}**

Here is an example of how it is supposed to work:[Sample GDocs spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvvkJKPw-5d9dFBEY2VrY2c0NUQ0elpyQ1dtbkF4TGc&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your question was not far from the previous one that I just tried to answer so I though I could continue and suggest a working solution to this (easy) problem...
so there it is, not the most elegant but easy and working.

```
function insertBlank() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var last = lastRowinCol(sh,'A');
  var colA = sh.getRange('A1:A'+last).getValues();
  var colB =  sh.getRange('B1:B'+last).getValues();
  var nA = [];
  var nB = [];
  for(n=0;n<last;++n){
  nA.push([colA[n]])
  nA.push(['']);
  nB.push([''])
  nB.push(['{'+colB[n][0]+'}']);
  }
  Logger.log(nA.length+' = '+nA)
  Logger.log(nB.length+' = '+nB)
  sh.getRange(1,1,nA.length,1).setValues(nA);
  sh.getRange(1,2,nB.length,1).setValues(nB);
}

function lastRowinCol(sh,col){
  var coldata = sh.getRange(col+'1:'+col).getValues();
  for(var c in coldata){if(coldata[c][0]==''){break}}
  return c
  }
```

That said, you should preferably ask more appropriate questions and show that you have tried before coming on sto make your shopping for free ;-)

---

**EDIT :** following a very pertinent [comment from Mogsdad on this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189695/add-timeline-when-cell-value-is-changed-google-script) I suggest you replace the for-next loop in `function lastRowinCol` with his code that iterates backwards so that it handles empty cells in the column. Moreover his code has an interesting construction since the loop limits and the condition are in the same statement.

```
function lastRowinCol(sh,col){
  var coldata = sh.getRange(col+'1:'+col).getValues();
  for (var c=coldata.length; (c) && coldata[c-1][0]==''; c--) {}
  return c
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this script. I have to say that I feel bad for giving the impression that I was shopping for free. In my defense, let me say that I am not a programmer and I was merely looking for help to complete a Creative Commons database project I have been working on for some time now. Please accept my apologies and allow me to thank you once more.

Comment: no worries, you don't need to apologise but you know the rules of this forum and you know you are not exactly following them but that's ok for me. If the script satisfies you please consider accepting the answer. Btw, I'm not a programmer either, I just learned a lot by practicing and asking/answering here and there...and I just like it ;-)